# running fixed effects plm R - city, year, quarterly data

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, panel-data, plm

I am trying to estimate a model using fixed effects in R using plm package. My data looks like the following below it is firm, city, year, quarter level. And each of these I observe sales, and income by firm and city level by year-quarter. My regression is income ~ sales. That is sales on income, but looking to control for firm, and city specific unobservables. I have 1000+ firms in my actual dataset.

```
fid = c(1,1,1,1,
    2,2,2,2,
    3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
    4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,
    5,5,5,5)

cityid = c(101,101,101,101,
       102,102,102,102,102,102,102,102,103,103,103,103,
       103,103,103,103,
       104,104,104,104,
       104,104,104,104)

year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000,2000,2000, 2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002,
     2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002)

qtr = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,
    4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)

df = data.frame(fid, cityid,year,qtr,sales = sample(1:4,7, replace=T),income=30:57)
```

I see the plm function takes in panel specified by individual-time. That is each individual is observed over various time intervals. Now how could I use the plm package to run:
1.) firm fixed effects 
2.) firm and city fixed effects
3.) firm, city, quarter fixed effects.

Could you distinguish? I am little confused regarding the time component, and wondering if I can use firm and city fixed effects too? In running the firm and city fixed effects, my panel would have each firm city repeated 4 times for the quarter, while each city may have multiple firms.

For 3.) can I combine firm, city using the plm command but explicitly control for quarter in the formula (like factor(quarter))?

Just wanted to get a clearer understanding of extending plm to estimate fixed effects, beyond just using time dimensions. I have already looked the vignette, but it is not totally clear. So any information would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused here.
The unit of analysis in your dataset is the yearly quarter (lets call it q_year, coded for example as 2000_1, 2000_2, etc.). So you would want to generate such a variable and use it to index the time dimension.

This you then could specify as follows:

```
model <- plm(income ~ sales + as.factor(q_year), data= df, index=c("fid", "q_year"), 
      model="within")
summary(model)
```

This model gives you time-fixed effects (yearly quarter) as well as firm-fixed effects. Note, that in your example data 'city' does not vary over time. So it would be consumed by the firm-fixed effect (the city location is a fixed firm characteristic!).

(note: do you have data for some firms ranging over multiple years? Your example data does not have this. You would want to condens your example data to a four wave design and just take the quaters as time dimension, because this data structure effectively hold year constant for every firm.)

Comment: Yes, I have data for many of the firms ranging over multiple years at the quarter level. So for eg., fid = 1, I have data from 2001q1 to 2010q4. Similarly for fid = 2, I have data from 2001q1 to 2010q4, but they may be in city 101 and 102 through out. This can also be seen in fid = 3 in my example.

Comment: Oh yes, I see. If city varies over time you can just include city-fixed effects as another covariate in the model. E.g., income ~ sales + as.factor(q_year) + as.factor(cityid)

Comment: That does the trick. In your specification above                                                                `model <- plm(income ~ sales + as.factor(q_year), data= df, index=c("fid", "q_year"), 
      model="within")
summary(model) `  But  I saw plm has the option to set `effect="twoways" ` for individual and time fixed effects. Any particular reason why your suggestion is to explicitly control `as.factor(q_year)` rather than using `effect = "twoways"` and not having to explicitly control `as.factor(q_year)`  ? ... in your case yearly quarter fixed effects is through the dummy.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `felm` as an alternative to `plm`. You specify all variables you want as fixed effects after a `|` in the formula.

```
model <- felm(income ~ sales | cityid + fid + qtr)
```

You should note that city fixed effects are not needed when firms are in a unique city only. The reason is that a firm fixed effects already holds everything constant that's not time-varying within a firm, i.e., their geographic location. Mathematically speaking, the fixed effects transformation subtracts the firm-level mean from the data, giving you a mean of zero. If you then form the city-level mean from all firms, so subtracting that mean from the data doesn't do anything.